# MongoDB / Mongoose ensure uniqueness between array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, schema, mongoose-schema

I've a schema which looks like this.

```
{
    username : "SomeUser",
    modules : 
    [
        {
           
                moduleName : "moduleName",
                moduleDesc : "moduleDescription"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

What do I want to achieve :

There should not be any duplicate "moduleName" in the moduleDetails object that is the part of "modules" array.

For example :

**This should NOT BE allowed.**

```
{
    username : "SomeUser",
    modules : 
    [
        {
            
                moduleName : "SameName",
                moduleDesc : "moduleDescription"
            
        },
        {
            
                moduleName : "SameName",
                moduleDesc : "moduleDescription"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

While, this **should be allowed**

```
{
    username : "SomeUser",
    modules : 
    [
        {
           
                moduleName : "SameName",
                moduleDesc : "moduleDescription"
            
        },
        {
            
                moduleName : "SomeOtherName",
                moduleDesc : "moduleDescription"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

Tried this, but it didn't help me in Mongoose.

```
username: 
{
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
},
modules: 
[
    {
        moduleName: 
        {
            type: String,
            unique : true, 
            required : true
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's no so easy, since mongodb is not supporting indexes on subdocuments. Maybe take a look here https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2226. They show how to do it with a schema validation for example.